# selenium driver disabling html 5 support

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, html5-appcache

I am trying to test a third party website/application, this is the only one we are having issue with...and can get through multiple pages, but there is one page in particular that when I am doing the following:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

Instance = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), chromeOptions.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));// NOTE: connection timeout of 600 seconds or more required for time to launch grid nodes if non are available.
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.ClassName("main-container"));
```

Simple right? I am getting the following message:

```
Driver does not support manipulating the HTML5 application cache. Use the HasApplicationCache property to test for the driver capability.
```

I am trying to find the way around it...or not to use the cache? Driver Options are like the following, and I see that this has changed too..so if this is where I change it...I am not sure how I would change it. I don't seem to be using the grid, just one singular test on a local stand alone server.

Comment: Why are you initializing `Instance` and referring to it by `Driver.Instance`?

Comment: They are not in the same file. The instance is in a driver.cs  that is inherited to all my test plans.  and the other is in a library referencing the screen that I am on.